# How do C#'s IIncrementalGenerators know if the compiler is doing an optimised build?

Tags: c#, optimization, build, sourcegenerators

I want to write an `IIncrementalGenerator` which has slightly different behaviour depending on if the compiler is doing a release or debug build. I know you in the CsProj you have the `Optimize` flag which controls some optimisations.

I want to check this `Optimize` flag during the `Initialize` call so that my generated code can perform more checks and generate more aggressive code which requires a lot more checks of the assembly. This isn't needed for debug builds as a simplified version of this can be generated which isn't as precise.

How do I get the state of `Optimise` or debug/release configurations in the `Initialize` call?